# playback audio to a non-default playback device in .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio, multimedia

How can I playback audio to a non-default playback device in .net? Help would be wonderful! Audio playback to the default playback device is easy, however machines can have multiple playback devices for many reasons, and many common application allow selecting a non-default device for playback and recording. Is there a way to do this hopefully avoiding pinvoke? media foundation or core audio? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KindReality,

[This](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) might be useful to you. NAudio has seemingly already wrapped up a few API's for you (and, I imagine, handles those low level calls so you don't have to). Scrolling down to "NAudio Features" will most likely reveal whether or not this is what you're looking for.